# Understanding tangent space basis

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Consider our manifold to be $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric.

In several texts that I've been reading, $\{\partial/\partial x_i\}$ evaluated at $p\in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is given as the basis set for the tangent space at p so that any $v\in T_pM$ can be written is terms of them. The texts further state that a $\partial/\partial x_k$ is a unit basis vector.

My question is why are the $\partial/\partial x_i$ unit vectors? I can see how they would give the canonical basis and be unit vectors if they acted on the standard coordinate curves $(x_1, ..., x_n)$, but don't they act on arbitrary functions? Or do they *only* act on the coordinate curves?

I have a feeling that I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the notation you are using. Let $(e_1,...,e_n)$ be the natural basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

One way to understand $\partial/\partial x_i$ is to imagine it as a derivation on the direction $e_i$ calculated at a point $p$. In this case, you can interpret $\partial/\partial x_i$ as the unit vector $e_i$.

To understand it better you should show that any given derivation on $C^\infty(V,\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. an element of $T_p \mathbb{R}^n$) is actually a linear combination of $\partial/\partial x_1, ..., \partial/\partial x_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that it can be viewed as a derivation in the direction $e_i$, but I still don't see how it is a unit vector because it can act on an arbitrary function and not just on the coordinate parameter $x_i$.

Comment: Well, let me ask you a question. How do you compute the norm of $\partial/\partial x_i$?

Comment: Well, that's part of what I'm not clear on. I assume that you let it act on some function evaluated at a fixed point p to get a number which gives you the norm.

Comment: In this case it is easy to define a norm. Suppose $v \in T_p \mathbb{R}^n$ is a derivation, you known that there exist a unique vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the action of $v$ on a function is in given by the derivation in the direction $w$. So, you define the norm of $v$ as the norm  of $w$.

Comment: @MaxReinholJahnke: I think $\partial/\partial x_i$  may be unbounded: take  $C^{\infty }([0,1])$ and  $\partial/\partial x_i=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}$. Then if $f(x)=e^{ax}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} e^{ax}}{\mathrm{d} x}=ae^{ax}\Rightarrow \left \| \frac{\mathrm{d} (e^{ax}/\left \| e^{ax} \right \|)}{\mathrm{d} x} \right \|=\left | a \right |$ and $a$ can be made a large as we please.

Comment: Max- Thanks so much for your help. I will have to think a little on this because there is something I'm still not understanding. ... So in the special case where $v=\partial/\partial x_k$ for some fixed k, the vector $w=e_k$?

Comment: @jeo15, a good reference is John M. Lie's book on Introduction to Smooth Manifold. Take some time to read the chapter on Tangent Vectors. There you will find a very good explanation about the meaning of this objects and also a very complete discussion about different definitions.

Comment: Ok, I will do so. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I read Lee's chapter on tangent vectors, but it still has not cleared things up for me. For example, in his proof of Proposition 3.2 b., he makes the statement "... and taking $f$ to be the $jth$ coordinate function ...." That is exactly the heart of my question. $f$ is supposed to be arbitrary, isn't it? Of course, if we choose $f$ to be a natural coordinate function then by construction $\partial_i f /\partial x_i$ is going to be 1 or zero. That's not my question. My question is why is $\partial_i/\partial x_i$ considered a unit vector since it can act on an arbitrary function?

Comment: I have two "exercises" that may help you to understand this concept. What is causing some confusion now is that you can't imagine $\partial/\partial x_i |_p$ as a vector, only as an operator acting on functions. Try to answer the following questions:
1) Suppose you have an isomorphism between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$. If $V$ is a normed space, how can you use the diffeomorphism to define a norm $W$? 2) How can you define an isomorphism between the spaces of derivations $Tp\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$? Maybe answering these two questions will help you to understand better your problem.

Comment: Hmm, those are tough exercises for me, a physicist, and not a mathematician. Of course I know what an isomorphism is and what a diffeomorphism is but that's about the extent of it. II'm guessing that you want me to see how to use one space to define a parameter that the other space lacks given an isomorphism between them.

Comment: I think the answer to 1. is to compute the norm of a vector in V and use the isomorphism to associate that norm with the corresponding element in W. As to 2, I would do exactly what is done and associate a derivation along a coordinate curve in $M^n$ (which is an element in $Tp\Re^n$) with a unit vector in $\Re^n$ (since $\Re^n$ is a vector space). One thing I have to add is that I'm not the one imagining $\partial/\partial x_i$ as a unit vector. It is asserted in a book I'm reading: *Geometry of Differential Forms* by S. Morita.

Comment: English isn't my native language, so I failed to express myself. You *must* to look to $\partial/\partial x_i |_p$ as a vector. Those two "exercises" were made exactly to help you doing that. I'm sorry for my mistake.

Comment: In the hint to the proof of Corollary 3.3 in J. Lee's book, he states flat out that $\partial/\partial x_i = D_{e_i}$. I still don't see how this is generally true given the fact the partial can act on an arbitrary function. If it acts only on a coordinate function, then yes I can see it's true and then we can associate it with the unit vector.

Comment: No problem with the English.

Comment: How do you define $\partial/\partial x_i |_p$ and $D_{e_i}|_p$?

Comment: $D_{e_e}$ is the derivation at p in the direction of $e_i$. I am having a problem with the definition of $\partial/\partial x_i$ because to me it is both a vector and an operator that acts on a function f at p as in the equation in Lee's book after 3.8.

Comment: @jeo15, on $\mathbb{R}^n$ one possible definition of $\partial / \partial x_i |_p$ acting on a smooth function $f$ is: $\partial / \partial x_i |_p(f) = \lim_{h \to 0} (f(p + h e_i) - f(p))/h$. Are you using this definition?

Comment: No. I am using a definition without the $e_i$

Answer (score 3):

If your manifold $M$ is embedded within $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say a surface within $\mathbb{R}^3$), it has a dimension, say $d$. So the tangent spaces have dimension less than $n$. Every (suppose it $C^\infty$ to begin with) manifold comes with the algebra $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ and it can be shown that every derivation $d$ of $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ is of the form "evaluation at a tangent vector", i.e., for $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ 
$$
d(f)[x]=f'(X_x)[x]
$$
where $X$ is in the tangent space. On the other hand $f'(X_x)=\sum_{i\leq n}a_i\frac{\partial}{\partial_i}(f)[x]$. That's why tangent vectors are operators and $X=\sum_{i\leq n}a_i\frac{\partial}{\partial_i}$. Why unit vectors ? in fact your manifold, as embedded comes with the metric inherited from that of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that it may happen that none of $\frac{\partial}{\partial_i}$ be in any tangent space (think of $M$ of eq. $x=y$ in the plane) but those who are, are unit vectors. Now, if your manifold *is* $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself ($M=\mathbb{R}^n$), the $\frac{\partial}{\partial_i}$ are a basis of $\mathfrak{Der}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}))$, the space of derivations of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}))$ hence

1. Each $d\in\mathfrak{Der}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}))$ is, in fact, a vector field and its evaluation at $p$ is a vector of the tangent space

   If the space is given a (Riemannian) metric (here it is the Euclidean structure) it provides a scalar product on every tangent space and here $(\frac{\partial}{\partial_i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is an orthonormal basis of it.

   As every derivation in a vector field, the intuition is that it is, at each point, the "speed vector" of an integral curve and the norm is the (scalar) speed. You, again, find a coherent result.